# What is the impact of lr_mult = 0?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, computer-vision, caffe, image-segmentation

I'm looking at some Caffe network-building code (in the BerkeleyVision [pascalcontext-fcn8s](https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org/tree/master/pascalcontext-fcn8s) net.py file), and I find this line:

```
L.Deconvolution(n.score_fr,
    convolution_param=dict(num_output=60, kernel_size=4, stride=2,
        bias_term=False),
    param=[dict(lr_mult=0)])
```

I'm wondering about what the `lr_mult = 0` term does. My first guess after looking at the documentation is that it should prevent any updates to the kernel weights, but that seems weird, because I assume that the default initialization is random. What does this do? Is there some other code or parameter file somewhere that is initializing the kernel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are correct. Setting `lr_mult=0` freezes the weights of the layer. The weights will be stayed fixed and will not change from their initial values throughout training.
2. If you follow the code, you'll see a call to [`surgery.interp`](https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org/blob/master/surgery.py#L46-L59), this function sets the initial weights of the upscaling layer **before** training begins. The weights are remaining fixed to these values due to the `lr_mult=0`.

Comment: What about kernel initialization? It seems that bilinear interpolation would be the goal, but I don't find where that gets done anywhere.

Comment: @JimBiard look at the function I linked to in the answer

Comment: @JimBiard if the answer resolved your issue, kindly *accept* it - answers take up valuable time for respondents